# Passing void to a parameter of incompatible type?

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm attempting to use a C function within my Objective-C project, and I'm having trouble getting them to mix.

I have the following function:

```
// 1. Pass in the cost function which takes in an array and gives out cost and gradient at the given input.
// 2. xVector should contain the initial point which is will be modified to reflect the optimum point
// 3. nDim is the dimension of xVector
// 4. maxCostCalls is the maximum number of times the cost function may be called
// return value:  1 -> Num of Cost function calls exceeded max specified in the argument. 2-> line search failed

int fmincg(void (*costFunc)(double* inputVector, double* cost, double* gradVector), double* xVector, int nDim, int maxCostFuncCalls); xVector, int nDim, int maxCostFuncCalls);
```

Here's the function I'm passing into the first parameter:

```
static void _fmincg_evaluate(id thisClass, LKDataset *inputFeatures, LKFeature *outputFeature, LKMatrixObject *initialWeights, double cost, LKMatrixObject *optimizedWeights) {
    cost = [thisClass costUsingLogisticRegressionWithInputFeatures:inputFeatures outputFeature:outputFeature andWeights:initialWeights];
    optimizedWeights = [thisClass optimizeWeightsUsingGradientDescentForInputFeatures:inputFeatures outputFeature:outputFeature andWeights:initialWeights];
}
```

Finally to call fmincg I do the following:

```
fmincg(_fmincg_evaluate(self, inputFeatures, outputFeature, self.weights, cost, optimizedWeights), inputFeatures->matrix, inputFeatures.elementCount, 50);
```

But I get the following error:

> Passing 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'void (*)(double *, double *, double *)'

Maybe it's the lack of sleep, but I'm a bit confused, being that I'm new to C.

Comment: The function prototype in your first code block isn't valid C syntax; I suspect that you made a mistake when copying and pasting it into this question. Also it's unclear what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to pass the result of calling the `_fmincg_evaluate` function instead of passing the actual `_fmincg_evaluate` function.

You want:

```
fmincg(_fmincg_evaluate, inputFeatures->matrix, inputFeatures.elementCount, 50);
```

The implementation of `fmincg` will be responsible for calling the passed in function pointer along with any arguments it needs.

Update: As pointed out by Adrian in the comments below, you can't pass your `_fmincg_evaluate` function as the first parameter to the `fmincg` function since the parameter types don't match.

Comment: Won't that result in a similar error? The first parameter to `fmincg` should have type `void (*)(double*, double*, double*)`, however `_fmincg_evaluate` has type `void (*)(id, LKDataset *, LKFeature *, LKMatrixObject *, double, LKMatrixObject *)`

Comment: @Adrian You are correct. I overlooked the difference in parameters. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Aww you're both correct. I went ahead and fixed all that. Thank you for spotting that!